# Santa Fe Factory installed remote starter causing my new car to not start

Tags: hyundai, intermittent-problems, santa-fe

I have 2012 Santa Fe. The car was working fine then all of a sudden it was loosing power when I was driving one day and wouldn’t star after that. I Replaced the alternator,starter switch,battery,fix the battery ground then came across an article that said the issue may be a factory installed remote starter. My car does have a  factory installed remote starter that I’m just now becoming aware of.  What the individual didn’t say on their post was how they fixed the problem.

Comment: Can someone tell me what I need to do to possibly fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

Disconnected it it’s fixed thank you